# Trying to make a CSGO game type thing, but whenever I execute the code it displays that you've won all items

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberGeneratorGame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*351);

        if (random1 <= 289) System.out.println( (random1) + "  You win a blue skin."); 
        if (random1 >=290 || random1 <=325) System.out.println( (random1) + "  You win a purple skin."); //want odds to be from 290-325
        if (random1 >=326 || random1 <=340) System.out.println ( (random1) + " You win a pink skin."); //want odds to be 326-340
        if (random1 >=341 || random1 <=347) System.out.println ((random1) + " You win a red skin!!!!"); //want odds to be 341 - 347
        if (random1 >=348 || random1 <=350) System.out.println ((random1) + "  You win a knife!!!!"); //want odds to be 348-350
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a CSGO Case Opening Simulator type thing. Whenever I execute this though, I get this:

```
167.0  You win a blue skin.
167.0  You win a purple skin.
167.0 You win a pink skin.
167.0 You win a red skin!!!!
167.0  You win a knife!!!!
```

Comment: This kind of typo is where learning to use a debugger comes in very handy.

Comment: Apparently you didn't read my comment in your other thread where I suggested using &&

Answer (score 1):

Use `&&` instead of `||`

```
 if (random1 <= 289) System.out.println( (random1) + "  You win a blue skin."); 

if (random1 >=290 && random1 <=325) System.out.println( (random1) + "  You win a purple skin."); //want odds to be from 290-325

if (random1 >=326 && random1 <=340) System.out.println ( (random1) + " You win a pink skin."); //want odds to be 326-340

if (random1 >=341 && random1 <=347) System.out.println ((random1) + " You win a red skin!!!!"); //want odds to be 341 - 347

if (random1 >=348 && random1 <=350) System.out.println ((random1) + "  You win a knife!!!!"); //want odds to be 348-350
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was working on this code earlier and someone said I need to use || when I was originally going to use &&.

Comment: Think about it logically, the value will always be >= 290 OR <= 325

Comment: Jeremiah's code below is probably better, but the compiler may be smart enough to optimize this for you anyay.

Answer (score 1):

Your flow of your if's is flawed.

```
public class NumberGeneratorGame
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        double random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*351);

        if (random1 <= 289)
        {
            System.out.println( (random1) + "  You win a blue skin.");
        }
        else if (random1 <=325)
        {
            System.out.println( (random1) + "  You win a purple skin."); //want odds to be from 290-325
        }
        else if (random1 <=340)
        {
            System.out.println ( (random1) + " You win a pink skin."); //want odds to be 326-340
        }
        else if (random1 <=347)
        {
            System.out.println ((random1) + " You win a red skin!!!!"); //want odds to be 341 - 347
        }
        else if (random1 <=350)
        {
            System.out.println ((random1) + "  You win a knife!!!!"); //want odds to be 348-350
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ((random1) + " You should never see this error"); // Just here to catch any errors
        }

    }

}
```